# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE' while creating function

Tags: sql-server

I am a complete newbie when it comes to MS SQL and have found this code online while searching. It seems like it would do exactly what I want, which is do a radius search based on Latitude and Latitude values.

However, I keep getting: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.** , which is the very first line of the code. My database is 2008 MS SQL

Here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance
            (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
            @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
            @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
            @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
        Returns Float
        AS BEGIN
        Declare @Temp Float

        Set @Temp = sin(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * sin(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) + cos(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Longitude2/57.2957795130823 - @Longitude1/57.2957795130823)

        if @Temp > 1
            Set @Temp = 1
        Else If @Temp < -1
            Set @Temp = -1

        Return (3958.75586574 * acos(@Temp) )

        End

        -- FUNCTION 
        CREATE FUNCTION LatitudePlusDistance(@StartLatitude Float, @Distance Float) Returns Float
        AS BEGIN
            Return (Select @StartLatitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / 4766.8999155991))
        End

        -- FUNCTION 
        CREATE FUNCTION LongitudePlusDistance
            (@StartLongitude Float,
            @StartLatitude Float,
            @Distance Float)
        Returns Float
        AS BEGIN
            Return (Select @StartLongitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / (4784.39411916406 * Cos(2 * @StartLatitude / 114.591559026165) * Cos(2 * @StartLatitude / 114.591559026165))))
        End


        -- ACTUAL QUERY 
        -- Declare some variables that we will need. 
        Declare @Longitude Decimal(8,5),
                @Latitude Decimal(8,5),
                @MinLongitude Decimal(8,5),
                @MaxLongitude Decimal(8,5),
                @MinLatitude Decimal(8,5),
                @MaxLatitude Decimal(8,5)

        -- Get the lat/long for the given id
        Select @Longitude = Longitude,
               @Latitude = Latitude
        From   qccities
        Where  id = '21'

        -- Calculate the Max Lat/Long 
        Select @MaxLongitude = LongitudePlusDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, 20),
               @MaxLatitude = LatitudePlusDistance(@Latitude, 20)

        -- Calculate the min lat/long 
        Select @MinLatitude = 2 * @Latitude - @MaxLatitude,
               @MinLongitude = 2 * @Longitude - @MaxLongitude

        -- The query to return all ids within a certain distance 
        Select id
        From   qccities
        Where  Longitude Between @MinLongitude And @MaxLongitude
               And Latitude Between @MinLatitude And @MaxLatitude
               And CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, Longitude, Latitude) <= 2
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thank you!!!

**EDIT:** Thank you very much to bluefeet and Aaron Bertrand for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: In addition to separating your batches using `GO`, [please use the `dbo.` prefix when creating/referencing objects, *especially* functions](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand hello Aaron, my server is on a shared environment, and the MS SQL database tables are all not inside of dbo., instead they are something like user21587. So my table would be user21587.qccities does that make a difference? I did try both my prefix and the dbo. prefix, and both are still giving me errors, now it says: Incorrect syntax near 'go'.

Comment: where exactly are you running this code? Have you tried just running each `CREATE FUNCTION` separately?

Comment: I am running it inside of a coldfusion page. And yes I've tried stripping everything except one function. I've done them one at a time, and all are giving me Incorrect syntax near 'go'. Something else must be going on since the SQL Fiddle below provided by bluefeet works just fine. Do you think it could have something to do with my database being on a shared environment? Do functions need special permissions to run or something? But then again, I'm not getting any weird permission errors...I'm getting an error of incorrect syntax :(

Comment: Did you try a single function without the `GO`? `GO` is not part of T-SQL, it is a batch separator for client tools like Management Studio. ColdFusion is probably passing that along to SQL Server and it doesn't understand the `GO`. So either send one function at a time from ColdFusion (without the `GO`), or use a better tool for creating objects and sending queries (e.g. Management Studio or whatever client interface the host provides you with).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think that did it. As I mentioned below, the function executes if I just put one function in the code without the ending GO. But, it looks like I won't be able to do 3 function inside of one code block. As soon as I add another function even w/o the go and just ending it with ";" it throws errors.

Comment: why do you need to create 3 functions in a separate code block? You only need to create the functions once. After you have created them in the database, you can reference them in subsequent queries.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Em I don't think I'm using the right terms. Before, I had those 3 functions inside my coldfusion page, they weren't functions inside the database...if that makes sense? I am just starting to grasp this whole function thing so I'm having trouble explaining it. I guess my next step is to use a SQL manager, and create the functions directly in the database (is that the right term?) so that I can then reference them inside my CF page like so dbo.myfunction(). Does that make sense? Thank you very much for your help by the way!!

Comment: So they were ColdFusion functions, not T-SQL functions, correct? T-SQL functions don't work the same way. You create them *once* in the database, and then you can reference them from other T-SQL code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand well they are SQL functions, I just didn't realize they needed to be treated differently than the standard sql statement like SELECT * FROM etc. Inside coldfusion you can put simple SQL statements like that to query records, but to use SQL functions, I'll have to add them to the database directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also end the each of create statements with a `GO` or semicolon:

Also, should add the schema to the function. For example the below uses the `dbo.` schema:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateDistance
            (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
            @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
            @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
            @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
        Returns Float
        AS BEGIN
        Declare @Temp Float

        Set @Temp = sin(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * sin(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) + cos(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Longitude2/57.2957795130823 - @Longitude1/57.2957795130823)

        if @Temp > 1
            Set @Temp = 1
        Else If @Temp < -1
            Set @Temp = -1

        Return (3958.75586574 * acos(@Temp) )

        End
        GO
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76f75) of all functions being created.

Comment: @JonEgerton You are right, I was updating my answer to include the missing `GO` and to suggest using `dbo.` or some schema.

Comment: @bluefeet thank you for your reponse. And I see that the sql Fiddle is working, however, when I add that same code into my page I now get: Incorrect syntax near 'go' Am i doing something wrong by having the functions and the actual query in the same sql block? Or? Maybe I am not 100% clear on how functions work :(

Comment: @Jennifer The `GO` is used to separate each batch and the creation of the function needs to be in separate batches.  If you take your queries and run those in a separate script or query window do they work after the functions are created?

Comment: @Jennifer you say "into my page" - what page are you talking about?

Comment: @bluefeet Well no, even if I remove EVERYTHING from my query window, except the very first create function, until the ending "go" I still get incorrect syntax near 'go'. I then tried just leaving the function batches in the query call and it also gives me the same error. In other words, I basically copied your SQL fiddle and just pasted that in, w/o my actual query that uses the functions, and I still get the error. Should a function be able to stand on its own? Without anything calling it later in the code?

Comment: @Jennifer Where are you running the script?  Are you running it in SQL Server Management Studio?  Do you have permission to create functions?   Do you have a specific schema that you should be working in?

Comment: @bluefeet I am sorry I will probably sound really stupid, but I am very new to SQL, all I've done in the past is run simple SELECT * FROM...WHERE etc stuff, just inside of my coldfusion page, wrapped in <cfquery> tags. That is where I'm placing this code. Do functions go somewhere else? I do have SQL Manager for SQL server, with which I can connect to my database, and it's a program that allows me to create foreign keys in my tables for example, is that the tool I need to use for functions?

Comment: @Jennifer I do not think you will be able to run multiple batches to create the functions inside your `cfquery` code.

Comment: @bluefeet I think you are right...I just tried just ONE function, w/o the ending "GO" like Aaron suggested, and that executed without error. So, what are my options? How do other people create functions? Can I place user defined functions, directly into my database somehow, and then just reference them in my query call? For example I know I can reference COUNT(*), which is built into SQL if I understand this correctly. So is there a way to "add" functions to my database?

Comment: @Jennifer Yes you will have to add the functions into the database, either you or your DBA. Then you will just need to reference them in your query.  You also will not be recreating them each time you use them. these would be added typically trhough SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @bluefeet thank you very much for your help! This has been very enlightening! But what do you mean by recreate them each time? I have to manually create them every time? Why wouldn't the database remember the function and just let me reference it like SELECT dbo.myfunction()?

Comment: @Jennifer bluefeet said you will *NOT* be recreating them each time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand aaaa I'm an idiot :(!! sorry ! Yes that makes sense :) Thank you both, I wish I could add both your answers as accepted, you help me so much with this. Thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try a single function without the `GO`. `GO` is not part of T-SQL, it is a batch separator for client tools like Management Studio. ColdFusion is probably passing that along to SQL Server and it doesn't understand the `GO`. So either send one function at a time from ColdFusion (without the `GO`), or use a better tool for creating objects and sending queries (e.g. Management Studio or whatever client interface the host provides you with).

I'm not sure why you think you need to create the three functions in a single code block instead of creating them separately (since your web page obviously has no clue about batches). You only need to create the functions once. After you have created them in the database, you can reference them in subsequent queries all day/week/month/year etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate multiple `CREATE FUNCTION` calls with `GO` OR `;` (or both - which one I prefer):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance
        (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
        @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
        @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
        @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
    Returns Float
    AS BEGIN
    Declare @Temp Float

    Set @Temp = sin(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * sin(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) + cos(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Longitude2/57.2957795130823 - @Longitude1/57.2957795130823)

    if @Temp > 1
        Set @Temp = 1
    Else If @Temp < -1
        Set @Temp = -1

    Return (3958.75586574 * acos(@Temp) )

    End;
GO

    -- FUNCTION 
CREATE FUNCTION LatitudePlusDistance(@StartLatitude Float, @Distance Float) Returns Float
    AS BEGIN
        Return (Select @StartLatitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / 4766.8999155991))
    End

    -- FUNCTION 
    CREATE FUNCTION LongitudePlusDistance
        (@StartLongitude Float,
        @StartLatitude Float,
        @Distance Float)
    Returns Float
    AS BEGIN
        Return (Select @StartLongitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / (4784.39411916406 * Cos(2 * @StartLatitude / 114.591559026165) * Cos(2 * @StartLatitude / 114.591559026165))))
    End;

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of `CREATE` statements in that SQL. They have to be separated into batches by putting `GO` between the statements.

This is revealed by the half of the message in SSMS:

> 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.

So to fix:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDistance
        (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
        @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
        @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
        @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
    Returns Float
    AS BEGIN
    ...
    END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION LatitudePlusDistance(@StartLatitude Float, @Distance Float) Returns Float
    AS BEGIN
        Return (Select @StartLatitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / 4766.8999155991))
    End

 GO

 CREATE FUNCTION... etc
```